# Are these two code snippets the same or do they differ in any way?

Tags: java, while-loop

I was working on implementing the union find problem where I encountered this snippet.

```
while (root != id[root])
        root = id[root];
```

Isn't it the same as

```
while ((root = id[root]) != id[root]);
```

except that may be the second construct executes the assignment operation at least once while the first construct may not execute it even once if the initial condition is false. Are there any other differences?

Comment: Your best bet is trying it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Only perform the assignment if the variable doesn't already have the value you are assigning?

Comment: While do vs. do while?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am not sure it is, especially when I want to understand any hidden differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are very different, think of the order in which they are executed.

In the first you check whether `root != id[root]` and *then* you assign `root = id[root]`.

In the second you first assign (nested) and *then* check.

The usual idiom for this is the `BufferedReader`:

```
String line;
while((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
}
```

If we change this to the first method:

```
String line;
while(line != null) {
     line=bufferedReader.readLine()
}
```

We won't even enter the while loop...

Answer (score 1):

No. See it this way-

```
int i;

while(i != 10)
```

vs

```
int i;
while((i = 10) != 10)
```